# How to convert categorical values into binaries in Java?

Tags: java, r, binary

Assume that I have a table including 2 columns (A and B):

```
  A          B
  blue      yellow
  blue      green
  red       green
```

I want:

```
A.blue A.red B.green B.yellow
 1      0     0         1
 1      0     1         0
 0      1     1         0
```

I can use acm.disjonctif in R. How can I get the same result when I use Java?

Comment: People working with Java do not necessarily have knowledge of R. You should explain the problem clearer...

Answer (score 0):

Hi try put colors in a boolean matrix , for example:

```
boolean color [] []= new boolean[4][3];
String A[] ={"blue","blue","red"};
String B[] ={"yellow","green","green"};

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

for (int j=0;j<3;j++){

  if(A[i].equal("blue")){
   color[i][j]=1;
}
}
```

}

OUTPUT 
Blue  1  1  0